# Variational Quantum Free Energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, energy

The quantum mechanical free energy $F$ is defined as
$$
e^{-\beta F} = \text{Tr}\left( e^{-\beta(H+\mu N)}\right)
$$
where $H$ is the Hamiltonian of the many body system, $\beta$ is the inverse temperature, $\mu$ is the chemical potential, and $N$ is the number operator. This formula above is computationally expensive for exponentially large systems.
Can we reduce the size of the problem by using a classical analogue representation of the free energy?
$$
F = \text{min}\left( \ \langle \Psi |(H+\mu N) |\Psi \rangle -k_B T \ln\left(D_\Psi \right) \ \right)
$$
where $\Psi$ is a many body quantum state, $D_\Psi$ is the degeneracy of states satisfing $H|\Psi\rangle = E|\Psi\rangle$, and $min$ means find a $\Psi$ that minimizes the free energy expression.